# How to set OpenFire to show user as Online for a given timeout even if connection is lost?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I have the following scenario:

1. OpenFire 4.0.2 XMPP server
2. Android app that connects to the server

In order to preserve battery I need to release the wake lock and let the phone go to sleep which closes the connection. At the same time server notices the lost connection and shows that user is offline. After a minute I use alarm to wake the phone, reconnect and check for messages (and then go back to sleep).

Is there a setting for a timeout that tells the server not to show the user as disconnected immediately after losing the connection? I need it to wait for a minute (for example) and if there is no reconnection from the app - then to show user as offline.

Comment: I think you just have to assume on CLIENT side online-offline cache/timer based on offline listener. It's possible to set some larger timeout or "never disconnect idle" on Openfire but I don't know if it's what you want.

Comment: @MrPk "never disconnect idle" works as long as socket is open. When the socket is closed (phone goes to sleep) openfire immediately shows the user as offline...

Comment: sure, then I can suggest only to write a plugin for Openfire that intercepts his own Presence.unaviable and modify to available after a look up on last logout from user. I have no code ready so I can't help more, a plugin is not that short to write.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I was also thinking for customizing the connection manager in order to notify with timeout the openfire server that the user has closed the socket...